# What is meant by spatial resolution in a particle detector?

Tags: particle-physics, particle-detectors, accelerator-physics, subatomic

I'm reading a document about a particle physics detector and its sub-detectors.
They mention that: ' its drift chamber has a spatial resolution of 130 μm'.
Can anyone please explain to me what is meant by that? How the spatial resolution is computed, is it a distance of some sort?
Does spatial resolution reflect how accurately a detector can detect the position of a particle?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's it. High spatial resolution means you can accurately trace out the trajectory of a particle through the interaction volume, and accurately pinpoint the creation spot of a certain particle of interest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) , do you know how do they get the spacial resolution generally? @niels nielsen

Comment: a common method is to place fine wires back and forth across the interaction volume and look for voltage changes on them, this lets you trace the movement of charged particles through it. another way is to have the interaction volume completely surrounded by particle detectors that only catch particles coming from one direction. Reactions that create those particles can then be pinpointed by looking at all the detectors and seeing where their pointing directions intersect.